# Is it possible to use Android Profiler with any hybrid-framework?

Tags: android, flutter, cordova, android-profiler

I am doing a comparison between Apache Cordova and Flutter regarding the use of hardware components like battery, CPU, RAM etc...

My question is it possible to use the Android Profiler tool in android studio with these two platforms or is it only possible doing it while writing a native application?

Thanks for any kind of answer.

Comment: For Flutter, it does seem like you should be able to profile it using Android Studio https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance